# Android Virtual Device Loads Very Slow

Tags: c#, android, asp.net, xamarin.android, xamarin-studio

I am using a remote desktop having configured Win 8.1, 3gb ram DDR2, 15gb HDD free space, latest Xamarin Studio Starter version with api 21 packages. When I try to debug a simple "Hello World" solution on studio, the manually created AVD loads too slow, even android home screen does not appear after 1 hour. What should I do  to speed up the process ?

Comment: I think this will help you [link](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1554099/5148289)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if your IDE supports it but you should really try out Genymotion, it changed my development time and testing significantly.

https://www.genymotion.com/

Comment: As per your information, I have installed genymotion and created a virtual device. When I try to start the device, it shows an error "Unable to start the virtual device. VirtualBox cannot start the virtual device."

Comment: Take a look at your Oracle VM Virtual Box and make sure the device is listed there.

Comment: When I try to start the virtual device from the Oracle VM Virtual Box, it shows an error "VT-x is not available (VERR_VMX_NO_VMX)."

Answer (score 0):

Considering your configuration, 1 hour is too much, try restarting first.

- If not go for your Android device(physical), I debug on my mobile(you don't have to wait for your mobile to start).
- You Can also go for [Genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com/) . Many find difficulty in genymotion setup. it is pretty simple though, [follow this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MWZ2rVFOQWw) If you'll understand once about VirtualBox  and IP, it'll be easy for next time

I would recommend 6GB Ram and i5 processor for performance lag problem. So if it is possible, you should upgrade your machine.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your responses. Finally I have resolved the issue by creating a low resolution Android Virtual Device (Nexus One) by Xamarin Studio.

But another problem arises, the published apk file is too large.Which steps need to be done to make it perfect ?

Comment: This is a different question, best to ask this in a fresh post and not as an answer

Answer (score 0):

You should try the Xamarin Android Player. In my experience it's the fastest option over Genymotion and Android's AVD images even with Intel's HAXM installed.

https://www.xamarin.com/android-player

Comment: Yes, I don't see why not. Although, if I understand your question, you are asking if it's ok to run a VM inside a VM? Then you would run into the obvious performance constraints and also, many of the underlying hardware optimisations for VM acceleration may not be exposed to VM's inside VM's, so performance may not be optimal.